# EFCore: Query multiple related data

Tags: razor, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to project related data but keep getting errors.

I have a list of projects, for each project there may be multiple Baselines set (or none), each Baseline contains multiple Milestones. The projected list of Projects should contain a property which contains a particular milestone in the most recently set baseline.

My model is in SQL through EFCore:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Baseline> Baselines { get; set; }
}

public class Baseline
{
    public int BaselineID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSet {get; set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BaselineDate> BaselineDates { get; set; }
}

public class BaselineDate
{
    public int BaselineDateID { get; set; }
    public int BaselineID { get; set; }
    public Baseline Baseline { get; set; }
    public int MilestoneTypeID { get; set; }
    public MilestoneType MilestoneType { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I define the projected class:

```
public class ProjectInfo
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ProjectStart { get; set; }
}

public IList<ProjectInfo> ProjectInfoList { get; set; }
```

And then in a function I try to use efcore to query the models:

```
ProjectInfoList = await _context.Project
     .Where(project => project.Branch == Branch)
     .Select(project => new ProjectSummary
         {
             ProjectID = project.ProjectID,
             ProjectName = project.Name,
             ProjectStart = project.Baselines
                 .DefaultIfEmpty(new Baseline { BaselineDates = new List<BaselineDate>() })
                 .OrderByDescening(b => b.DateSet)
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 .BaselineDates
                 .Where(d => d.Comment == "Project Start")
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 .Date
          }
       .AsNoTracking()
       .ToListAsync();
```

This works fine as long as there is a Baseline for each Project. However when a project exists without a Baseline a null exception is thrown.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(IEnumerable source, Func predicate)

I try adding in .DefaultIfEmpty(new Baseline()) but it throws more exceptions.

Comment: What is `b.DateSet`?

Comment: Sorry, b.DateSet is a DateTime on the Baseline entity. I've updated the question.

Comment: No problem, it happens. Consider looking at the Gert's answer, it's similar to what I was going to propose. And let us know if it does solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that Entity Framework translates the whole LINQ expression into SQL (well, more precisely, *tries* to do that). Since there is no notion of null references in SQL you can safely use an expression that in C# code (or: LINQ-to-objects) would have thrown a null reference exception.

But that aside, the offending sub query can be rewritten so that even in LINQ-to-objects it won't throw an exception if the collection properties aren't null:

```
ProjectInfoList = await _context.Project
     .Where(project => project.Branch == Branch)
     .Select(project => new ProjectSummary
         {
             ProjectID = project.ProjectID,
             ProjectName = project.Name,
             ProjectStart = (from bl in project.Baselines
                from bd in bl.BaselineDates
                where bd.Comment == "Project Start"
                orderby bl.DateSet descending, bd.Date descending
                select (DateTime?)bd.Date).FirstOrDefault()
          }
       .AsNoTracking()
       .ToListAsync();
```

I do this in query syntax for better readability. The `from ... from` construct is `SelectMany` in method syntax. `SelectMany` syntax, when data from both parent and children is required (`bl.DateSet, bd.Date`), is pretty awkward.

Comment: @Ivan Nice one!